# typescript : can't access base class methods from derived class

Tags: typescript, openlayers

I've tried to extend an Openlayers control class to a custom class in typescript . Even after making `super()` call , I can't access the super class methods ,

```
import olControl from 'ol/control/control';
@Component({
  selector: 'track-me',
  template: require('./zoomhistory.html'),
  //styles: [require('./map.scss')]
})
  export class ZoomControl extends olControl {
    static parameters = [];
    constructor() {

      let zoomCtrlButton = document.getElementById('trackme');
      super({ element: zoomCtrlButton });   
      var self = this;
      debugger;
      self.setMap(this._map);
    }
  }
```

it will show 
`property setMap() doesn't exist on type ZoomControl` , 
can't compile then. But when i put debugger and hover on `this` i can see setMap method from developer console . Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: The problem is probably with your import of `olControl`.  Please add it to the question.

Comment: no problem with import control , as i can create a new instance of that class as well . I've updated question

Comment: I still can't reproduce the error.  If you publish a repository that reproduces the problem for you, I will look at it.

Comment: ol/control/Control will match the typings.

Answer (score -1):

- Make sure ‘setMap’ is defined as public method in `olControl`
- Try to access to this method as `self[“setMap”](this._map)`

Comment: olControl is a class of Openlayers library ,here im trying to a create a custom control by extending openlayers control . i think you are out of context